# JSON value not getting appended to the Html correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am having a JSON object

```
var jsonString =[
    {
        "key": "Monday, June 18, 2012",
        "value": "10 00 AM|_mod,11 00 AM|_mod,12 00 PM|_mod,13 00 PM|_mod"
    },
    {
        "key": "Tuesday, June 19, 2012",
        "value": "13 00 PM|_mod,13 30 PM|_mod,14 00 PM|_mod,14 30 PM|_mod,15 00 PM|_mod"
    }
];
```

I have two drop-downs I am trying to match the key selected from the first drop-down with the key in the JSON and populate the second drop-down with the appropriate values.
I want the option tag to look like this

```
<option value="10 00 AM|_mod">10 00 AM</option>
```

but I am seeing this

[image]

I think the empty spaces in the 10 00 AM|_mod are causing a problem when the DOM is getting created.

This is my JS code.

```
$('#event_date').change(function() {
    var event_date = $("#event_date").val(); // first drop-down val
    var time_type = null;
    var time = null;
    for (var x = 0; x < jsonString.length; x++) {
        if (event_date == jsonString[x].key) {
            var value = jsonString[x].value;
            console.log(value);  // output: 10 00 AM|_mod,11 00 AM|_mod,12 00 PM|_mod,13 00 PM|_mod
            var value_split = value.split(",");
            for (var i = 0; i < value_split.length; i++) {
                console.log(value_split[i]);    // works fine at index 0 I get 10 00 AM|_mod
                time_type = value_split[i].split("|");
                time = time_type[0];
                $('#timeslotIdentifier').append("<option value =" + value_split[i] + ">" + time + "</option>");
            };
        };
    };
});
```

Is there an encoding problem ? I tried adding breakpoints and it looks fine but when I inspect the element I am seeing this.

[image]

Comment: This is not JSON, it is a JavaScript array. Your question does not seem to have anything to do with JSON.

Comment: Don't magic strings like `"13 00 PM|_mod,13 30 PM|_mod,14 00 PM|_mod,14 30 PM|_mod,15 00 PM|_mod"` rather defeat the point of json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating an **unquoted** attribute value.

You should use jQuery instead:

```
$('<option />').text(time).val(value_split[i]).appendTo('#timeslotIdentifier');
```

Comment: overlooked that part. Thanks a lot !! Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#event_date').change(function() {
    var event_date = $("#event_date").val(); // first drop-down val
    var time_type = null;
    var time = null;
    for (var x = 0; x < jsonString.length; x++) {
        if (event_date == jsonString[x].key) {
            var value = jsonString[x].value;
            console.log(value);  // output: 10 00 AM|_mod,11 00 AM|_mod,12 00 PM|_mod,13 00 PM|_mod
            var value_split = value.split(",");
            for (var i = 0; i < value_split.length; i++) {
                console.log(value_split[i]);    // works fine at index 0 I get 10 00 AM|_mod
                time_type = value_split[i].split("|");
                time = time_type[0];
                $('#timeslotIdentifier').append($("<option>").attr({value: value_split[i]}).text(time));
            };
        };
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.val()` is definitely better in this case, but in case you don't know where is the error at, it is here:

```
//Nope. (Missing quotes in HTML)
$('#timeslotIdentifier')
    .append("<option value =" + value_split[i] + ">" + time + "</option>");

//Yep.
$('#timeslotIdentifier')
    .append("<option value =\"" + value_split[i] + "\">" + time + "</option>");
```